# How to insert data from text file into phpmyadmin sql databse?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a text file containing data in multiple rows and columns. A snapshot is given below:

[Data from my text file (del.txt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puvgn.jpg)

I want to insert all the data in a single column (column name: Enrolment (say)) of the table 'year'. I have tried the following code.

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '/xampp/htdocs/docs/del.txt' INTO TABLE year FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  ");
```

With this, only the first column of the data file get inserted into the table. But I want to insert all the data in the specific column 'Enrolment'. My knowledge is limited in this field. Any clue please.

Comment: MySQL can't handle reading multiple values on one line into one column. You'd probably do better to load the data in PHP (use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)) and split it into multiple inserts there

Comment: I don't typically use that, but a quick search said this `During the upload, using the “FIELDS TERMINATED BY” option, you can specify the comma field delimiter as shown below. Use this option only when the field values are separated by anything other than TAB`  I just do it with SQL, using the command line, or I scrape it off the internet ... ha ha.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but wouldn't it be much easier to replace the tabs for newlines and then do the import? 

E.g. with stream editor `sed -i 's/\t/\n/g' del.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I usually load data with query in the database.

So I suggest you to copy the .txt file to an excel sheet and create INSERT query for each row of the data.

You can use `CONCATENATE` function.

For example, if you have data in columns A and B, you can write the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO year(Enrolment) VALUES('", A2, " ", B2, "'")
```

in the second row of the sheet and pres enter. After that click drag the square bold corner till the end of the last row.

Copy all the select statements and execute them in the phpMyAdmin window.